# Background SVG won’t scale in Bootstrap div column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, svg, responsive-design

I’d like be able to stretch a large SVG over a `<div>` that is embedded in Bootstrap’s `<div class="col-xs-N">`.

The code is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">    
    <style type="text/css">
      .my-img {
      background-size: cover;    
      padding-bottom: 100%;
      background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ec/Arctic_big.svg) no-repeat center center;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-xs-offset-5 col-xs-2">
    <div class="my-img"> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-5">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put your `background-size: cover;` after `background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ec/Arctic_big.svg) no-repeat center center;`. In your case `background-size` is invoked before loading the image, so it didn't take effect.

Change:

```
.my-img {
  background-size: cover;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ec/Arctic_big.svg) no-repeat center center;
  }
```

to:

```
.my-img {
      padding-bottom: 100%;
      background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ec/Arctic_big.svg) no-repeat center center;
      background-size: cover;
      }
```

Example [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/learningloop/z5tsLsq6/2/)

Comment: Brilliant, thank you.Also just came to realize that the notion “large SVG” doesn’t make that much sense.

Comment: The order of statements matters. A fundamental quality to be sure, yet all of a sudden CSS in my eyes just took on a whole lot more complexity. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just add **min-height** to your css.

```css
 .my-img {     
        padding-bottom: 100%;
        min-height:100vh;         background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ec/Arctic_big.svg) no-repeat center center;
        background-size: cover;       
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">    
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-xs-offset-5 col-xs-2">
    <div class="my-img"> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-5">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, this one works too. However it’s the reordering of background: ’url(...);' and ’background-size: cover;' as suggested by @learningloop that ultimately saves the day.